# Output float at maximum precision within a field width

Tags: c++

I am writing an array of float numbers that I want to fit within a fixed width.
The numbers can be positive or negative with any value.
How can I get the most precision written? 
Preferably without unnecessary zeroes.

E.g. with  width=9 (and one space before each field)

```
 123456789 1.2345678 1.2345e+9 -1.234e+9 -1.23e+10      2.5
```

I think I have to to do some calculations...

Comment: And what have you tried? What are you using to output these values?

Comment: setw(9) << f may write more than 9 chars, same for printf(%9g). I also tried using QString::setNum(), and tried to compute the width and precision for the "%g" format based on the magnitude of the number.

Comment: What have you tried and what is your code.

Comment: my code is 'for (float f : array) cout << " " << formatFloat(f,9);'

Comment: And what if `formatFloat`?

Comment: The float type has an intrinsic precision, if you convert from decimal to float and back to decimal again then you never get more than 6 significant digits.  So 123456789 is already far out of reach, those last 3 digits will just be random noise.  You'll lose more digits if you do math on the float, can be a lot of them if you subtract two values that are almost equal.  So this is not arbitrary, focus on not displaying more than you can deliver.  Google "c format float with specific number of significant digits" to find hits.

Comment: Sorry, yes I know that. But for a double that is not the case. My question is how to format a floating point value with as much precision as possible within a fixed field width. I suspect that I cannot use the stream manips or the C formatting strings directly, but have to do some branching based on the magnitude of the number.